# Passwordless Custom Auth Flow in awsmobileclient

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm having an issue when attempting sign in doing a custom auth flow for passwordless sign in.
I followed the docs here: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/authentication#custom-authentication-in-amplify

I got a awsconfiguration.json like the one there, with those two sections including the custom part.

I am facing two issues with this which are:

I have written a Lambda pre-authentication trigger to validate if the user is already existing in the database (RDS) or not. But when I try to sign in, this lambda method does not invoke.

Second is when I sign in using the CustomAuthFlow calling method `AWSMobileClient.getInstance().confirmSignIn()` the first time, it allows me to sign in without any issue. Thereafter when I sign out and try to sign in again, it trigger the lambda service Define auth challenge and Create auth challenge twice.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you setup properly the lambda functin in the Cognito Triggers section?
Did you check  "Enable lambda trigger based custom authentication" in the App Clients section?

Comment: @Ricardo yes. I enabled it.

Comment: I have a similar problem in iOS, but it is due to an iOS bug in the AWS library. Maybe there is a similar problem in Android.
https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/2101
But about if you try that using a web app? Like this one:
https://github.com/mobilequickie/amplify-passwordless-sms-auth/tree/master/webClient/angular

Comment: @Ricardo Yes. I think its a bug in Android. We are still  developing web app. I will update you once we test it.  And Did you resolve your issue in iOS. Cheers.

Comment: Nope, I created the bug yesterday. I am still researching. I wonder if it is easy or not doing all those steps without the SDK.

Comment: @Ricardo  I  am also researching the bug. Let you know , when I get solution for this. Cheers